# Python Pandas DataFrame: how to locate an element by positional (int) in index *and* by label (str) in columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Just saw this:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated

Apparently the `.ix()` operator is now deprecated. Wondering how to do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-05']))
wanted_int_index = df.index.get_loc('2017-01-04', method='ffill') # index_id = 2
wanted_str_column = 'a'
value = df.ix[wanted_int_index, wanted_str_column] # value = 2
print(value)
# 2
```

My understanding is that `.loc()` excepts label (str) for both index and columns, while `.iloc()` excepts position (int) for both index and columns. Am I missing a usage here?

Answer (score 0):

`loc` should work for non-datetime indexing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=range(10),columns=['A'])
print(df.loc[1,'A']) #this works
```

For datetimes, like you have, you need to index using them. Ie,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}, 
index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-05']))
wanted_int_index = df.index.get_loc('2017-01-04', method='ffill') # index_id = 2
wanted_str_column = 'a'
value = df.loc[df.index[wanted_int_index], wanted_str_column] # value = 2
print(value) #this works
```

Comment: Using `df.loc[df.index[...], ...]` also appears to be the way that the documentation recommends to replace previous behaviour.